# Detect when a custom GUI popup menu is visible

Tags: popup

I wrote this function to popup a simple menu with each opened buffer as entry:

```
function! PopupBufferList()
   
   let menuName = "BuffersList"
   silent! exec ":aunmenu ".menuName
   " All 'possible' buffers that may exist
   let b_all = range(1, bufnr('$'))
   " Unlisted ones
   let b_unl = filter(b_all, 'buflisted(v:val)')
   for nbuff in b_unl
      let menuitem = substitute(bufname(nbuff), '\.', '\\.', 'g')
      :exec ":amenu ]".menuName.".".menuitem." :b ".string(nbuff)."<CR>"
   endfor
   :exec ":popup ]".menuName
   
endfunction
```

Is there a way to know, from vimscript, when this menu is visible (i.e. `pumvisible()`) ? Because I would like to map `<Tab>` to `<Down>` when this menu is visible.

Comment: You might want to consider using the newer popup functions instead of the menu commands (which IIUC have a very different appearance in graphical Vim). With the new-style popups, you can also have custom key-handlers.

Comment: I know but I am using Vim 8.1 (and 7 on another machine where I am not the admin of it)

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no equivalent of `pumvisible()` for GUI menus.
2. Opening a GUI menu doesn't trigger any event but it is probably possible to use something like `:doautocommand User menuFooBar`.
3. Which would be useless in this case, because Vim mappings don't affect the GUI anyway.

Using `:help popup-window`, as suggested in the comments, would be a better idea for the reason mentioned but also because it works the same in the GUI *and* the TUI.

If you can't use that feature, I'm afraid you are left with few options:

- use a fuzzy search plugin like fzf.vim and configure its keybindings,
- populate the quickfix list with your buffers and make filetype-specific mappings,
- or use `:help inputlist()`, which is not really interactive.

FWIW, here is a quickfix variant of your snippet:

```
function! MakeQFItem(key, val)
    return {'bufnr': a:val}
endfunction
let b_all = range(1, bufnr('$'))
let b_unl = filter(b_all, 'buflisted(v:val)')
let b_map = map(b_unl, function('MakeQFItem'))
call setqflist(b_map)
```